# Issue with Angular routing and Lay loaded module

Tags: angular

Given the following routing configurations:

The following module is imported inside `AppModule`

```
const routes: Routes = [
 ...
  {
    path: "lazy",
    loadChildren: "app/modules/lazymodule#LazyModule"
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    component: DemoComponent,
    pathMatch: "full"
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

The following module is imported inside `LazyModule`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: LazyComponent,
    pathMatch: "full"
  },
  {
    path: ":test",
    component: TestComponent
  },
  {
    path: "try",
    component: TryComponent,
    pathMatch: "full",

  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]
})
```

Once `LazyModule` has loaded, I can navigate to `TestComponent` by e.g.

```
this.router.navigate(["/lazy", "hello"])
```

but not to `TryComponent` by

```
this.router.navigate(["/lazy/try"])
```

***What's wrong with the last one?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/lazy/try` is matched by:

```
{
    path: ":test",
    component: TestComponent
}
```

so you should be navigated to `TestComponent` with `try` as value of `:test` parameter.

If you want to change that, then change the order of routes so that route with `path: "try"` is before the route with `path: ":test"`.